# TF-Lite-Converter with Tensorflow-Extended Pipeline (Chicago Taxi Pipeline Example)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tfx

**Goal: TFX -> TF Lite Converter -> Deploy models on mobile/IoT devices**

I am currently learning the [Tensorflow Extended](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx) with its [Chicago Taxi Pipeline Example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/tree/master/examples/chicago_taxi_pipeline).
The pipeline is done running (although through a lot of hardships) and the **Pusher** Component has emitted a **Tensorflow SavedModel** file (.pb).

However, a new problem is encountered here:
By Tensorflow nightly/1.13.1 (tried both) and Python 2.7.6, I can generate, save and load a **SavedModel** (a model for mnist digit data for testing the utility) with some simple python code, such as `saved_model.simple_save` and `saved_model.loader.load`, but I keep running into errors when applying on the models the **TFX Pusher** emits, as follows.

(Maybe I did something wrong with the TFX Pipeline?)

#### The code I used:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], "/home/tigerpaws/taxi/serving_model/taxi_simple/1553187887")#"/home/tigerpaws/saved_model_example/model")
    graph=tf.get_default_graph()
```

#### Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a6978b82c3d2> in <module>()
      1 with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
----> 2     tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], "/home/tigerpaws/taxi/serving_model/taxi_simple/1553187887")#"/home/tigerpaws/saved_model_example/model")
      3     graph=tf.get_default_graph()

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.pyc in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    322               'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    323               instructions)
--> 324       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    325     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(
    326         func, new_func, 'deprecated',

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.pyc in load(sess, tags, export_dir, import_scope, **saver_kwargs)
    267   """
    268   loader = SavedModelLoader(export_dir)
--> 269   return loader.load(sess, tags, import_scope, **saver_kwargs)
    270 
    271 

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.pyc in load(self, sess, tags, import_scope, **saver_kwargs)
    418     with sess.graph.as_default():
    419       saver, _ = self.load_graph(sess.graph, tags, import_scope,
--> 420                                  **saver_kwargs)
    421       self.restore_variables(sess, saver, import_scope)
    422       self.run_init_ops(sess, tags, import_scope)

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.pyc in load_graph(self, graph, tags, import_scope, **saver_kwargs)
    348     with graph.as_default():
    349       return tf_saver._import_meta_graph_with_return_elements(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 350           meta_graph_def, import_scope=import_scope, **saver_kwargs)
    351 
    352   def restore_variables(self, sess, saver, import_scope=None):

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.pyc in _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements(meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices, import_scope, return_elements, **kwargs)
   1455           import_scope=import_scope,
   1456           return_elements=return_elements,
-> 1457           **kwargs))
   1458 
   1459   saver = _create_saver_from_imported_meta_graph(

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.pyc in import_scoped_meta_graph_with_return_elements(meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices, graph, import_scope, input_map, unbound_inputs_col_name, restore_collections_predicate, return_elements)
    804         input_map=input_map,
    805         producer_op_list=producer_op_list,
--> 806         return_elements=return_elements)
    807 
    808     # Restores all the other collections.

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.pyc in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    506                 instructions)
--> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.pyc in import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map, return_elements, name, op_dict, producer_op_list)
    397   if producer_op_list is not None:
    398     # TODO(skyewm): make a copy of graph_def so we're not mutating the argument?
--> 399     _RemoveDefaultAttrs(op_dict, producer_op_list, graph_def)
    400 
    401   graph = ops.get_default_graph()

/home/tigerpaws/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.pyc in _RemoveDefaultAttrs(op_dict, producer_op_list, graph_def)
    157     # Remove any default attr values that aren't in op_def.
    158     if node.op in producer_op_dict:
--> 159       op_def = op_dict[node.op]
    160       producer_op_def = producer_op_dict[node.op]
    161       # We make a copy of node.attr to iterate through since we may modify

KeyError: u'BucketizeWithInputBoundaries'
```

There was also another attempt, where I tried to convert the **SavedModel** into a **GraphDef (Frozen Graph)** so I could give the converter another try.
The conversion would need a `output_node_names`, which I don't know; 
Neither could I find where the model is saved in the code (so maybe I can spot the output node names somewhere).

Any ideas on the problem or alternative ways? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** can somebody help create tags? I have not reached 1500 reputation, but this question is really about `tfx` / `tensorflow-extended`

Comment: Your question is bit confusing to me. Is your question regarding Chicago Taxi Example or regarding MNIST Digit Dataset.

Comment: Since that code is not confidential (Chicago Taxi and MNIST) , if you can share the entire code, we may understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion caused; the problem actually is caused by the reading of the SavedModel file.

In the SavedModel, there is an operation `BucketizeWithInputBoundaries`, that is not defined in `op_dict`.

This is still in Google's TODO list, commented in two of their scripts.

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/a315f9deb8c78447f92b376c2888bf1a0ae44266/tfx/components/evaluator/executor_test.py#L22) and [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/9b8c8a18f201c49aec7477fdf81477d2ada96adc/tfx/components/model_validator/executor_test.py#L22). (Github links):

```py
# TODO(jyzhao): BucketizeWithInputBoundaries error without this.
```

After importing the specified script this problem is solved.

```py
from tensorflow.contrib.boosted_trees.python.ops import quantile_ops  # pylint: disable=unused-import
```